# How put all calculations from multiple models to GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Now, I am running MTCNN(implement on Tensorflow) for face recognition on the GPU.

Since MTCNN using three models, PNet, RNet, ONet, and between them, running some steps by NumPy.

For example, when get the output from PNet, it will do some numpy.transpose on the output to get boxes, then pass these boxes to RNet.

So I suppose only PNet, RNet and ONet models would be run on GPU, other NumPy steps would be on CPU. Then it will copy the output from GPU memory to main memory. It would be quite waste time.
Is my guess right?

For improve the performance, I want to put all MTCNN calculations on GPU.

Anyone would give me some idea or an example?

Comment: If you are using Keras, I recommend taking a look at https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-a-keras-model-on-multiple-gpus

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the memcopy between GPU and CPU can be not that expensive, I would measure this first.

If you use TensorFlow-GPU, all the operations will be automatically performed on GPU whenever possible. Of course, this will not work with NumPy steps. So, the way to go would be replace the NumPy routines with the TensorFlow ones. TF has quite rich tensor manipulation library, which is similar in API to NumPy. Compare, for instance [np.transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) to [tf.transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose).

Comment: Thanks. I use tensorflow.python.client.timeline to profile the performance for Tensorflow. But I have no idea how to measure the time of memcopy between GPU and CPU.  Also, I know tf.transpose. But I am not sure how to add this routine after PNet, and cannot find any example about it.

Comment: Obviously, we need code sample from you to try translating it into tensorflow.